# Update multiple inputs with altField in Datepicker

Tags: jquery, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Can someone please tell me the correct way to modify the following:

```
$("#datepicker01").datepicker({

  numberOfMonths: 2,
  minDate: dd, 
  maxDate: '+1M +31D',
  hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
  altField: 'input#chooseDate01',
  altFormat: 'DD, d MM yy',
  beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays
 });
```

I need to add a further 5 to the altField element, ie 'input#chooseDate02' etc. Is it as simple as:

```
altField: 'input#chooseDate01' 'input#chooseDate02', and so on.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the altField attribute takes a jQuery selector so you can do this

```
altField: 'input#chooseDate01, input#chooseDate02'
```

see http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

or you could just select by class e.g.

```
altField: 'input.choose-date-class'
```